# Dapper map single record to parent and child

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I want to map a flat row to a simple parent/child object using Dapper.

I am unsure how to do this, here is a simple example of the tables, query and class to map to.

Project Table

> id, name, status_a, status_b, status_c

Status Table

> id, description

Query

```
select   
    prj.id,   
    prj.name,   
    a.description,  
    b.description,   
    c.description  
from project prj  
join status a on prj.status_a = a.id  
join status b on prj.status_b = b.id  
join status c on prj.status_c = c.id
```

Class to map to

```
class Project
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}

class Status
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to use Multi-Mapping.

```
sqlConnection.Query<Project, Status, Project>(yourQueryString, 
     (project, status) => {
          project.Status = status;
          return project;
     },
     splitOn: "description");
```

Or something like that. I haven't tested this code out, but this is the basic idea.

`sqlConnection.Query<Project, Status, Project>` is basically telling Dapper that your SQL query is going to return two objects (Project and Status). This is inferred by the first two types in the generic parameters. The third (Project) tells Dapper that this Dapper call should ultimately return a Project.

The first parameter is going to be your query, like normal.
The second parameter is some function that will receive the project and status from your query, and expect you to return a project object. Here, we're just assigning the status to the project's Status property.

`splitOn` lets you tell Dapper "at what point in the SQL query does the "Project" object end and the "Status" object begin.

```
select   
    prj.id,   
    prj.name,   
    a.description,  
    b.description,   
    c.description  
from project prj  
join status a on prj.status_a = a.id  
join status b on prj.status_b = b.id  
join status c on prj.status_c = c.id
```

You can see that your project object ends at `prj.name` and your status object begins at `a.description`.

Comment: You probably want splitOn: "id", not splitOn: "description".